# how can I run a script interactively, but as though under cron?

Tags: bash, cron

During the process of developing a script, typically I work interactively
in the bash shell:
write, test, edit, test, repeat.

But if I intend to run the script under cron,
this approach may fail.
This is because my bash shell may have access to more tools than cron has.

For instance, a perl script
may fail to run under cron even though it runs on the command line,
because the necessary cpan modules might be
available only under my `$HOME` directory.

Also, `%ENV` in a perl script invoked from my shell contains many variables defined under `$HOME/.bash_profile`.
For instance, `$ENV{stackoverflow}` is a path under which I edit text files before posting them to stackoverflow.

One way to test a script intended for cron is
to look at the clock,
set up a crontab job for a few minutes after "now",
and wait for it to
be invoked.
This means that one repeatedly edits in `crontab -e`,
trying to get the time just right,
and each time one waits a few minutes for cron to invoke the script.

Thus, is there a way, instead,
to run a script under the identical conditions
that it would face if it were running under cron,
but to do this interactively,
so that one can more quickly edit, test, repeat?

I do not want to enhance the cron environment
to emulate or approximate my bash environment.
I want to run a script in the same parsimonious
environment in which scripts run under cron.

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to replicate the cron environment.\

Answer (score 0):

Try this command :

```
(cd
 env -i HOME="$HOME" LOGNAME=$LOGNAME SHELL=/bin/sh\
    $(perl -ne 's/"//g; print unless (/^\s*#/)' /etc/environment)\
    $(perl -ne 's/"//g; print unless (/^\s*#/)' /etc/default/locale)\
    bash /path/to/your-bash-script arguments < /dev/null
)
```

Replace `/path/to/your-bash-script arguments` as appropriate.

（ If you need definitions in $HOME/.bash_profile, you can do :

```
BASH_ENV=$HOME/.bash_profile bash /path/to/your-bash-script arguments
```

)

Once tested, you can put following in crontab for a real test :

```
* * * * * bash /path/to/your-bash-script arguments
```

I tested the snippet on Ubuntu. You might need to adapt if you use other unixes or MacOS. Particularly when /etc/environment or /etc/default/locale contain spaces (or other special characters).